# calculating an associative array of different units

Tags: php, associative-array

Im trying to add up all the quantites of a certain hazard element, which has multiple units types. If the unit is not listed then it would simply not be included (eg no 0 values). Then return an array of totals in a alternative key based format.

I would attempt it myself but I think I would make a mess of it. Can someone suggest an elegant way of caculating my array of elements to get the desired result?

**Array:**

```
//Raw Data to be caculated

Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [hazard] => irritant [quantity] => 1 [unit] => F)
    [1] => Array ( [hazard] => corrosive [quantity] => 2 [unit] => F ) 
    [2] => Array ( [hazard] => health [quantity] => 1 [unit] => F ) 
    [3] => Array ( [hazard] => toxic [quantity] => 1 [unit] => F ) 
    [4] => Array ( [hazard] => environmental [quantity] => 4 [unit] => l )       
    [5] => Array ( [hazard] => health [quantity] => 1 [unit] => l ) 
    [6] => Array ( [hazard] => toxic [quantity] => 2 [unit] => l ) 
    [7] => Array ( [hazard] => irritant [quantity] => 4 [unit] => g ) 
    [8] => Array ( [hazard] => corrosive [quantity] => 2 [unit] => g ) 
    [9] => Array ( [hazard] => toxic [quantity] => 3 [unit] => g ) 
    [10] => Array ( [hazard] => irritant [quantity] => 3 [unit] => K ) 
    [11] => Array ( [hazard] => toxic [quantity] => 2 [unit] => K ) 
    [12] => Array ( [hazard] => environmental [quantity] => 1 [unit] => V ) 
    [13] => Array ( [hazard] => health [quantity] => 2 [unit] => V ) 
    [14] => Array ( [hazard] => irritant [quantity] => 2 [unit] => l ) 
    [15] => Array ( [hazard] => toxic [quantity] => 3 [unit] => l ) 
    [16] => Array ( [hazard] => corrosive [quantity] => 3 [unit] => g ) 
    [17] => Array ( [hazard] => environmental [quantity] => 4 [unit] => g )) 

    etc
```

**Desired Result:**

```
//Array of totaled unit types

Array ( 
   [irritant] => Array( [g] => 4 [l] => 12, [K] => 5, [F] => 2),  
   [corrosive] => Array( [g] => 3 [l] => 7, [K] => 5),
   [hazard] => Array( [g] => 12 [l] => 18, [V] => 2)) 

   etc
```

Comment: Why not give it a shot? It's easy, and if you get stuck, we'll help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a destination array and loop through the original array making tests and calculation before inserting / updating the result of the destination array. Something like this :

```
<?php
$clean = array();
foreach ($raw_array as $r) {
    $type = $r['hazard'];
    $unit = (isset($r['unit'])) ? $r['unit'] : "";
    $qty = $r['quantity'];
    if (!empty($r['unit'])) // or any other filter for the units
    {
        $clean[$type][$unit] = (isset($clean[$type][$unit])) ?
            $clean[$type][$unit] + $qty :
            $qty;
    }
}
?>
```

Now your `$clean` variable holds the info with the desired structure.

Comment: Thanks this works, but im quite noob at php...havnt used ':' and '?' much before, and unsure how to understand this. Il do sum research on that syntax....unless you care to explain?

Comment: Sure, it's called ternary operation. It's an if-then-else value affectation. The syntax is the following :

$destination_variable = (condition) ? value_if_true : value_if_false;

You could also read more about this here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#PHP

Comment: Thank you for the extra info...that clarifies things nicely!